I can not install the pfx file in dynamics 365 plugin project when i get it from source control
I have a Dynamics 365 plug-in source that was written a few years ago.
The source is on tfs. After a few years, I want to take it to work on another system. When I run the project that I get, it gives the error that the signature file (pfx) is not installed. I want to install it, it asks me for a password. But I had put a signature without password on the project. When I sign the project on the new system, when registering it, it gives an error that the assembly you are registering is not the same as the assembly you registered before, and it does not register.
If anyone can help, I would be grateful.

It is not possible to update an existing plugin assembly with a different strong name, but you can install a new assembly version.
Increment the major and/or minor version of the plugin project. Build it and register the dll in CRM as a new plugin assembly. Transfer the steps and images from the old version to the new one and remove the old version.

Dynamics 365 Plugins use the signature in order to be registered inside the system. If you replaced the signature you can't update the existing plugin (also if the assembly name is the same) because the signature doesn't match.
If you are not able to recover the password of the previous signature, you will need to unregister the previous plugin and register the new one.
Make sure you keep track of all the steps and images are registered (with their filtering as well).
